# DOS batch file to display netsh channel output

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, ms-dos, netsh

I'm trying to get wifi Channel output from netsh command to be 2.4GHz or 5GHz

The following provides me with Channel output:

```
netsh wlan show interface name=Wi-Fi | findstr "Channel"
```

Output is "Channel      : 161"

2.4GHz = (Channel 1 - 11) OR 5GHz = (Channel 36 - 177)

I am having problems in a batch file to save the netsh output to a variable and then evaluate the variable, if <=11 it's 2GHz OR >= 36 but <=177 it's 5GHz

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%r in ('netsh wlan show interface name=WiFi^|findstr "Channel"') do Set Channel=%%r` This will leave a space before the %%r but you shouldn't need to trim it for your use.  Add a `echo "%Channel%"` to see the results.  I *could* write this whole batch file for you but I HIGHLY suggest that you take the tidbit I gave you and solve the rest.  Use `if /?` to figure out the greater than and less than logic.

Comment: I got it to work if wi-fi is enabled, however, if not enabled I get output "36 was expected at this time." @echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%r in ('netsh wlan show interface name=Wi-Fi ^| findstr "Channel"') do Set Channel=%%r

if %Channel% GEQ 36 if %Channel% LEQ 177 (echo Wi-Fi 5GHz) else (if %Channel% GEQ 1 if %Channel% LEQ 11 (echo Wi-Fi 2.4GHz) )

if "%Channel%"=="" (echo Wi-Fi not enabled)
 
set "Channel="

Comment: Thanks @iTwasnTme.  I thought of that too. (great minds blah blah blah). I was trying to make it as simple as possible by slightly tweaking *his/her* code directly as it was.  This line runs without error on my machine and I didn't need to escape the eq.

Answer (score 0):

Got the script to work just as I needed it, now I can use it in our RMM tool. @SeñorCMasMas thanks for the initial help

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%r in ('netsh wlan show interface name=Wi-Fi ^| findstr "Channel"') do Set Channel=%%r

if [!Channel!] EQU []  (echo Wi-Fi Not Connected) 
if !Channel! GEQ 36 if !Channel! LEQ 177 (echo 5GHZ)
if !Channel! GEQ 1 if !Channel! LEQ 11 (echo 2.4GHZ)
```